# problem on finding representations

Tags: harmonic-analysis

i am currently pursuing a course in basic harmonic analysis.i have gone through a lot of texts but i am really finding difficulty to proceed in the following problem:

(1) find a representation of  $\Bbb Z_2$ on $\Bbb R^2$

i have no clue how to proceed in this problem and am really sorry if the question is too basic for stack exchange.

please give brief explanation

thanks in advance....

Comment: What do you mean by $\mathbb{R}_2$?

Comment: sorry...i have edited the question